# How do I use the delay method in a way where I can still check if the mouse is clicked during it?

Tags: java, click, mouse, delay

I need to be able to call the delay method, but during it constantly check if the mouse has been pressed. This is my code so far for my delay method:

```
public void delay() 
  {
     for (int i = 0; i<100;i++) 
     {
        try 
        {
           Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) 
        {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        if (isClicked)
             {ClickedDuringDelay = true;
             System.out.println("PRESSED");}
     }
  }
```

PRESSED is never printed out when I click during the delay, and I am not sure why.
Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Try using the volatile keyworld : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

Comment: adding to @Vdolez comment: make isClicked volatile

Answer (score 0):

You can use the swing timer for this purpose

```
boolean clicked = false;

javax.swing.Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (clicked) {
       ...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Would I have to import anything at the beginning of my code?

Comment: And could I just replace this code inside my delay method?

Comment: this tutorial could be useful to you: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you need to wait (block) until a click is performed ... so for this I would do something like this

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class BlockUntilCliked {
    /** The lock object */
    private final Lock lock;
    /** Condition to be triggered when a click is performed */
    private final Condition clicked;
    /** Flag to indicate that the mouse was clicked */
    private boolean isClicked;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public BlockUntilCliked() {
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        clicked = lock.newCondition();
    }

    /**
     * method to be called on a click
     */
    public void doClick() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            this.isClicked = true;
            clicked.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void waitForClick() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            // do something before block

            // wait until not message was handled
            while (!isClicked) {
                clicked.await();
            }

            // do something after

        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns <code>false</code> if a timeout occurred or the block was unsuccessful
     */
    public boolean waitWithTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        long nanos = unit.toNanos(timeout);

        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            boolean timedout = false;
            // wait until no click was handled
            while (!isClicked) {
                if (nanos <= 0) {
                    timedout = true;
                    break;
                }
                nanos = clicked.awaitNanos(nanos);
            }

            // do something after it timed out

            return !timedout;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

by using this approach you will actually wait as long as a click is triggered ... no more, no less(, or the operation times out).

hope it helps

Comment: This looks helpful my only worry is that I need the code to keep running if the user doesn't click after a few seconds, how would i do that?

Comment: you can use the one with timeout, in my example you could call `waitWithTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, and this will timeout after 10 seconds, returning `false`, if the user do clicked it, it will return `true`